# How to create a page which lists all categories with its ratings

Tags: categories, plugin-wp-postratings

I want to create a "**Score Board**" for all categories with its current total ratings. I am using [WP-PostRatings plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/) to rate every posts.

I would like to create a page which shows all categories with its average ratings. Each category will gain or lose ratings as the posts under it does.The Scoreboard page will sort the Winners and Losers.

It would be nice to show the change in ratings in a timeline graph, but it can wait if it is too much work.

Edit: Appreciate your help!

So far, i tried all available plugins which i could find.I am not an avid coder. If you could suggest any plugins or hacks, it would be a great help. I would like to get the **SUM** of all ratings.

Comment: Hi, do you want to get the total ratings count or average?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? The way you're asking this question is a "do this for me". If you can show us the effort you've put into solving this question, it will help us help you. We incite members to attempt something.

Comment: @JackJohansson: I am using a negative ratings too. So a sum of all post ratings will help.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan: Excuse my language, english is not the first language for "most" of us.

Comment: The plugin doesn't support average rating for categories. However, i can write a code for you to loop every category and post, calculating the average score. But this might use a lot of resource depending on the number of your posts/categories. What is the approximate number of categories and posts that you have?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have couple of hundred posts and around 50 categories. Can we do a cron?

Comment: No couple of hundreds is not much. I was expecting above 50k post. I will write it after i get back from work.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire function to the page that you want to have your average ratings:

```
<?php
// Lets get the id of every existing category
$output_categories = array();
$categories = get_categories($args);
//We loop through every category to calculate the average rating score of it's posts
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $post_ids = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts'   => -1, // get all posts.
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => $category->cat_ID,
            ),
        ),
        'fields'        => 'ids', // Only get post IDs
    ));
    // Time to calculate the average rating score of each category
    if ( $category->count == 0 ){
        echo 'Average rating in <a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'"> '.$category->cat_name.'</a> is : No rating ';
    } else {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($post_ids as $postID) {
            $sum += the_ratings($postID);
        }
        $average_in_cat = (intval($sum / $category->count)*100)/100;
        // Alright, we have the average rating score for this category. Let's show it
        echo 'Average rating in <a href="'.get_category_link($category->cat_ID).'"> '.$category->cat_name.'</a> is : '.$average_in_cat;
    }
}
?>
```

There are few things that i have to mention about this function, which are:

1. I don't know what is the output of `the_ratings()` function. This function should return an integer / float for the code to work. Since i didn't have the plugin, i couldn't verify it's output. If it's anything other than a number, then you have to convert it to integer / float, or dig the plugin's code and find a function that returns a number.
2. The list is not sorted. To sort it, you can use either JavaScript, or store the output inside an array and use PHP to sort it.
3. I tested this on my own website with +5,000 posts distributed over 500 categories, and it took about 2 seconds for the code to finish up. So it won't take longer than a second in your case.

Anything else, just let me know.

Comment: Hi Jack, i am getting the below error. `<1883 id="post-ratings-1844" class="post-ratings" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" data-nonce="2468824908">Vote DownVote Up ` for all posts and at the end it shows the _average rating for **category name** is 0_

Comment: I checked the DB, the rating are stored as integer `rating_rating` in a seperate table.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you are using it the right way? [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUlAZ.jpg) is an image of this code working properly on my blog. Try and use `echo the_ratings($postID)` and use a real post's ID, see if it returns an integer.

Comment: It is not an integer. It shows `<1883 id="post-ratings-1844" class="post-ratings" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" data-nonce="2468824908">Vote DownVote Up`I will try to study the script you sent and figure out how i can get the ratings into it. Appreciate it. If you have anymore tips which might help.Thanks.